# Scapy Packet Filtering FROM an IP and with Destination Port 23

Tags: filter, scapy, packet, sniffing

I am trying to set a scapy packet filter to ONLY capture packets that are coming FROM a particular source or IP address AND that are destined for PORT 23.  This is the syntax I have so far but I think it is wrong because I think this syntax tells scapy to capture ONLY packets that are GOING TO this IP address.

```py
pkt = sniff(filter='host 8.8.8.8 and port 23', prn=print_pkt)
```

I think this syntax is not doing what I need it do.  I've tried searching for syntax that would tell scapy to only capture packets COMING FROM 8.8.8.8 but this is all I could find and I think it tells scapy to capture packets GOING TO 8.8.8.8.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Scapy filters are from a type called BPF, you can see the syntax [here](https://biot.com/capstats/bpf.html).

In your case, I think what you want to do is-

```py
filter='src host 8.8.8.8 and dst port 23'
```

Your original syntax is not distinguishig between source and destination, so it will filter packets from/to ip `8.8.8.8` and from/to port 23.